# "for limit must be a number" error in roblox (Data Saving and Loading)

Tags: for-loop, lua, lua-table, roblox

I leveled up my character and got some items, when i rejoined, it didn't load my previous data, It gave me level 0 and didn't load any items (it didn't give any output for level problem, but it gave this output for item problem: 'for' limit must be a number), but PLD.ItemNumber is a number, because It is from "ItemNumber" variable in the saving function. How to fix it? Code:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService");
local PD = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerData");

function SaveData(Player)
    local TableSave = {};
    TableSave.Level = Player.PlayerData.Stats.Level.Value;
    local TableItems = {};
    local ItemNumber = 0;
    for i,v in pairs(Player.PlayerData.Items:GetChildren()) do
        ItemNumber = ItemNumber + 1;
        TableItems["Item"..ItemNumber]={};
        local TI = TableItems["Item"..ItemNumber];
        TI.ItemName = v.Name;
        TI.Level = v.Level.Value;
        TI.Damage = v.Damage.Value;
    end
    table.insert(TableSave,TableItems);
    TableSave.ItemNumber = ItemNumber;
    PD:SetAsync(Player.userId,TableSave);
end

function LoadData(Player)
    local success, err = pcall(function()
        PLD = PD:GetAsync(Player.userId);
    end)
    if success then
        Player.PlayerData.Stats.Level.Value = PLD.Level;
        for i = 1,PLD.ItemNumber do
            local CurrentItem = Instance.new("Folder");
            CurrentItem.Name = PLD[1]["Item"..i].ItemName;
            local Lv = Instance.new("IntValue");
            Lv.Name = "Level";
            Lv.Value = PLD[1]["Item"..i].Level;
            Lv.Parent = CurrentItem;
            local Dm = Instance.new("IntValue");
            Dm.Name = "Damage";
            Dm.Value = PLD[1]["Item"..i].Damage;
            Dm.Parent = CurrentItem;
            CurrentItem.Parent=Player.PlayerData.Items;
        end
    else
        print("ERROR IN GET ASYNC");
    end
end

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(plr)
    repeat wait() until plr.PlayerData;
    SaveData(plr);
end)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    repeat wait() until plr.PlayerData;
    LoadData(plr);
end)
```

Comment: Can you print the value of `PLD.ItemNumber`?  It might happen that it is `nil`

Comment: you are right, it's nil.. how to fix that?

Comment: Probably, you're trying to load data but no data was previously saved.  Try to replace `if success then` with `if success and PLD.ItemNumber then`